# converting a string variable to a char

Tags: java, string, char

Is there a way to convert a String variable of the type `"X"` to a character ?

```
String state = "X";
char c_state = convertToChar(state);
```

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
char c_state = state.charAt(0);
```

Comment: I laughed out loud at this ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert it into a char array as follows, which could be quite useful if the String contained more than 1 character.

```
char[] charArray = state.toCharArray();
```

Comment: That creates a copy of the array, which might turn out to be slightly less efficient. (I don't know how well `charAt` gets optimised.)

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach

```
char c_state = state.toCharArray()[0];
```